# Rails/MongoDb Search and Refine Search Implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongoid3

I have a search functionality in my app which works as the following

1. Homepage: user selects location from a drop-down and then enters a search key-word and searches to get a set of results
2. Search Page (REfine Search Options): Once the user hits this page from the above he will be provided with more options to refine the search and narrow the results.

Right now we are implementing as follows but i am assuming as the paramenters increase over 5-7 the number of combinations will increase the number of if-else-elseif statement as well.

```
#refine search
    @search = params[:search]


    if params[:city].present? && params[:location_ids].present? && params[:search].blank?
      @blood_banks = BloodBank.where(
        { :city_id => "#{@city}" }).where(
        { :location_id.in => params[:location_ids] })
    elsif params[:search].present? && params[:location_ids].blank?
        @blood_banks = BloodBank.where(
          { :bb_name => /#@search/i })
    elsif params[:search].present? && params[:city].present? && params[:location_ids].present?
        @blood_banks = BloodBank.where(
          { :city_id => "#{@city}" }).where(
          { :location_id.in => params[:location_ids] }).where(
          { :bb_name => /#@search/i })
    end
```

Which is the best way to implement the same.

How do you achieve below code,

```
if params[:gender].present?
      if params[:gender] == "male"
      @doctors = Doctor.where( :gender => "Male")
      end
      if params[:gender] == "female"
      @doctors = Doctor.where( :gender => "Female")
      end
      if params[:gender] == "any"
      @doctors = Doctor.where( :gender => "Male") || Doctor.where( :gender => "Female")
      end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Mongoid's `where` returns a `Mongoid::Criteria` and `Mongoid::Criteria` responds to `where` by returning another `Mongoid::Criteria`. This means that you can build your query piece by piece:

```
@blood_banks = BloodBank.all
if params[:city].present?
  @blood_banks = @blood_banks.where(:city_id => params[:city])
end
if params[:location_ids].present?
  @blood_banks = @blood_banks.where(:location_id.in => params[:location_ids])
end
...
```

As far as the second part goes, if you're searching for any gender then just leave it out entirely, then you can do things like:

```
@doctors = Doctor.all
genders = { 'male' => 'Male', 'female' => 'Female' }
if genders.has_key? params[:gender]
  @doctors = @doctors.where(:gender => genders[params[:gender]]
end
```

Searching for any gender is the same not filtering on gender at all so the `nil` and `'all'` cases are the same. Then you can handle the input and `:gender` values with a simple lookup table.

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple parameter search"?

Comment: suppose i want to search input name with location and gender name..!! How it will achieve from your code.. Need some technical explanation?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean. The first example covers as many parameters as you have and the second covers your update.

Comment: Suppose i want to search ABC location name in XYZ city name, In above case how you will search???